# Event Driven IO And Blocking vs NonBlocking

Tags: c, optimization, io, blocking, nonblocking

Can someone explain to me how event-driven IO system calls like select, poll, and epoll relate to blocking vs non-blocking IO?

I don't understand how related -- if at all, these concepts are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `select` system call is supported in almost all Unixes and provides means for userland applications to watch over a group of descriptors and get information about which subset of this group is ready for reading/writing. Its particular interface is a bit clunky and the implementation in most kernels is mediocre at best.

`epoll` is provided only in Linux for the same purpose, but is a huge improvement over `select` in terms of efficiency and programming interface. Other Unixes have their specialised calls too.

That said, the event-driven IO system calls do not require either blocking or non-blocking descriptors. Blocking is a behaviour that affects system calls like `read`, `write`, `accept` and `connect`. `select` and `epoll_wait` do have blocking timeouts, but that is something unrelated to the descriptors.

Of course, using these event-driven system calls with blocking descriptors is a bit odd because you would expect that you can immediately read the data without blocking after you have been notified that it is available. Always relying that a blocking descriptor won't block after you have been notified for its readiness is a bit risky because race conditions are possible.

Non-blocking, event-driven IO can make server applications vastly more efficient because threads are not needed for each descriptor (connection). Compare the Apache web server to Nginx or Lighttpd in terms of performance and you'll see the benefit.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it spawns a thread (or chooses one from a pool) for each connection in each worker process.

Comment: I think a thread-per-connection server can be almost as fast as an event-driven one. The cause of Apache's slowness and bloat is not threads but the gigantic amount of overhead involved in handling each request. `pthread_create` only costs about the same amount as 2-3 `open` calls, and of course if you already have the thread blocked on `accept` before the connection arrives, the cost is even lower.

Comment: @R..: Well, but what about context switching? If the threads correspond to the number of CPU's then it's OK, but what if you have thousands of threads (connections)?

Comment: It would take some benchmarking to determine for sure, but I'm doubtful that switching between contexts which share the same virtual memory is going to be significantly more expensive than a "heavy weight" syscall like `select`. Maybe I'll make one to test - a simple threaded webserver with static content only is only a couple hundred lines of code. :-)

Comment: if you expect to be able to read without blocking after being notified that a descriptor is ready via select or epoll, then how is it more efficient to use non-blocking sockets over blocking sockets?

Comment: @Bob: As R.. has pointed out in his answer, race conditions are possible so that a `read`/`write`/`accept` call blocks on a blocking descriptor even after you have been notified that it's ready for the particular operation. With a non-blocking descriptor, you would just immediately get `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` without suspending the application.

Comment: @R: I believe your benchmark has already been performed and discussed: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: @loan: That site's pretty old, from a time when using threads, especially on Linux, was a complete joke. (The atrocious hack known as LinuxThreads was still mainstream...)

Comment: @Ioan A bit late, but since this thread was just pushed to top: [Here's](http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf) another comparison, this time done with not only a modern thread library but also the right selectors (at least as far as I can see). Clearly not that clear-cut as some people want to make it out

Answer (score 6):

They're largely unrelated, except that you may want to use non-blocking file descriptors with event-driven IO for the following reasons:

1. Old versions of Linux definitely have bugs in the kernel where `read` can block even after `select` indicated a socket was readable (it happened with UDP sockets and packets with bad checksums). Current versions of Linux *may* still have some such bugs; I'm not sure.
2. If there's any possibility that other processes have access to your file descriptors and will read/write to them, or if your program is multi-threaded and other threads might do so, then there is a race condition between `select` determining that the file descriptor is readable/writable and your program performing IO on it, which could result in blocking.
3. You almost surely want to make a socket non-blocking before calling `connect`; otherwise you'll block until the connection is made. Use `select` for writing to determine when it's successfully connected, and `select` for errors to determine if the connection failed.

Comment: +1, You might also add a well-known race with listening TCP socket where client drops the connection attempt in-between `select` and `accept`.

Answer (score 0):

`select` and similar functions (you mentioned a few) are usually used to implement an event loop in an event driven system.

I.e., instead of read()ing directly from a socket or file -- potentially blocking if the no data is available, the application calls select() on multiple file descriptors waiting for data to be available on *any one of them*.

When a file descriptor becomes available, you can be assured data is available and the read() operation will not block.

This is one way of processing data from multiple sources simultaneously without resorting to multiple threads.